# An interior point in the triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Suppose $P$ is an interior point of a triangle $ABC$ and $[AP]$, $[BP]$, $[CP]$ meet the opposite sides $[BC]$, $[CA]$, $[AB]$ in $D$, $E$, $F$ respectively. Find the set of all possible values of the following quantities can take:

> $$ \frac{|AP|}{|PD|}+\frac{|BP|}{|PE|}+\frac{|CP|}{|PF|}\\
> \frac{|AP|\cdot|BP|\cdot|CP|}{|PD|\cdot|PE|\cdot|PF|}
> $$

Answer (score 0):

If you drag $P$ to one of the corners, say $A$, then both expressions diverge to infinity. Since, while $\frac{|AP|}{|DP|}$ converges to zero, both $\frac{|BP|}{|EP|}$ and $\frac{|CP|}{|FP|}$ goes to infinity *roughly* same speed. Therefore there is no upper bound to these expressions.

As for the lower bound, i can only say that this happens when $P$ is on the centroid; giving a lower bound of $6$ and $8$ respectively. However, i cannot prove this fact, even though clearly there is no counterexample.

Comment: Hint for the lower bounds: van Aubel's theorem ( http://www.irmo.ie/6.Menelaus.pdf ) and AM-GM.